# tslint:dsiable does not work. What is a probable reason?

Tags: typescript

Despite having set `tslint:disable` I get tslint warnings.

The specific warnings I get are:

```
[ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit | undefined'.
(parameter) options: string

[ts] Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
(parameter) response: Response
```

This is my code.

```
/* tslint:disable */

// imports 
export async function fetchUrl(url: string, options: string) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(async (response) => response.json())
    .then((data: any) => data.data);
}

// other code

/* tslint:enable */
```

Why do I get these warnings even if I have disabled tslint?

How can I get rid of the error messages for this file?

Comment: These are errors from typescript compiler and not from tslint. You can use _// @ts-ignore_ above the line with the error to suppress it. (You can't suppress errors for code block, but only for single line)

Answer (score 3):

These errors are from the TypeScript compiler itself, as indicated by `[ts]` in the errors.

The following will get rid of the errors, but you'll need to check anything using the function is doing so correctly. i.e. with a valid `options` parameter.

```
export async function fetchUrl(url: string, options: RequestInit) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(async (response: Response) => response.json())
    .then((data: any) => data.data);
}
```